# Multiline footer with PDFMake

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I am trying to create a multiline footer with [pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake); what I was able to do until now:

```
const docDefinition = {
    footer: [
        {
            stack: [
                { text: "Line 1" },
                { text: "Line 2" },
                { text: "Line 3" },
                { text: "Line 4" }
            ], style: 'footer'
        }
    ],
    styles: {
        footer: {
            fontSize: 6, bold: true, alignment: 'center'
        }
    }
};
```

While this creates what I want, the style is not correct. As soon as I increase the font size, the bottom line starts to disappear. If I set the font size to 12, only the first two lines appear in the generated PDF on the server-side.

What change do I need to make here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add margin to the page and you can accommodate as many lines as you want. e.g. Enter the code below in pdfmake playground: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

// playground requires you to assign document definition to a variable called dd

```
let textFooter = `
    A 12.4% discretionary service charge will be added to your bill. All prices are inclusive of VAT. Thank You!\n\n
    This is line 2 - 263139\n
    Line 3 comes here\n
    Go big or go home!!!

    `;

var dd = {
    header: function(currentPage, pageCount, pageSize) {
    return [
      { text: 'simple text\naaa\nbbb\nccc\nddd', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 9 },
    ]
  },
    footer: function(currentPage, pageCount, pageSize) {
    return [
      { text: textFooter, alignment: 'center', fontSize: 9 },
    ]
  },
  // margin: [left, top, right, bottom]
    pageMargins: [ 40, 60, 40, 100 ],
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ]
    
}
```

In the code above, I have set margin bottom to 100 which gives us space to include 4 lines.